# How to restructure a column using 2 datasets in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 2 datasets which look like:

```
Gene        Druggability
Gene1       KINASE
Gene2       DRUGGABLE GENOME
```

```
Pathway      Gene
Pathway1     Gene1/Gene2/Gene3
Pathway2     Gene3/Gene1/Gene2
Pathway3     Gene1/Gene4
```

I am trying to add data from the first dataset into the second dataset so it corresponds with the genes and their order listed in the second dataset, like this:

```
Pathway      Gene                Druggability
Pathway1     Gene1/Gene2/Gene3   KINASE/DRUGGABLE GENOME/NA
Pathway2     Gene3/Gene1/Gene2   NA/DRUGGABLE GENOME/KINASE
Pathway3     Gene1/Gene4         KINASE/NA
```

I've been looking into reshaping with tidyr but I haven't gotten very far - are there any functions that can help with what I'm looking for?

```
drugs <- structure(list(Gene = c("TLN2", "PDGFC", "PIK3R3", "PIP5K1B", 
"VEGFA"), Druggability = c("KINASE", "DRUGGABLE GENOME", "CLINICALLY ACTIONABLE", 
"KINASE", "CLINICALLY ACTIONABLE")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

genes <- structure(list(Pathway = c("Pathway1", "Pathway2", "Pathway3"
), Gene = c("Gene1/Gene2/Gene3", "Gene3/Gene1/Gene2", "Gene1/Gene4"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Your "Genes" in `drugs` data are named differently than the Genes in `genes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there are less verbose ways:

```r
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

genes %>% 
  mutate(Gene = str_split(Gene, "/")) %>% 
  unnest(Gene) %>% 
  left_join(drugs, by = "Gene") %>% 
  group_by(Pathway) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(Gene, Druggability), ~ifelse(is.na(.x), "NA", .x))) %>% 
  summarise(Gene = str_c(Gene, collapse = "/"),
            Druggability = str_c(Druggability, collapse = "/"))
```

This returns (something like)

```r
  Pathway  Gene              Druggability              
  <chr>    <chr>             <chr>                     
1 Pathway1 Gene1/Gene2/Gene3 KINASE/DRUGGABLE GENOME/NA
2 Pathway2 Gene3/Gene1/Gene2 NA/KINASE/DRUGGABLE GENOME
3 Pathway3 Gene1/Gene4       KINASE/NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` and `gsubfn`:

```
library(gsubfn)
library(dplyr)
genes %>%
  mutate(Druggability = gsub("Gene\\d+", "NA", gsubfn("Gene\\d+", setNames(as.list(drugs$Druggability), drugs$Gene), Gene, perl = TRUE)))
```

Resulting to:

```
    Pathway              Gene               Druggability
1: Pathway1 Gene1/Gene2/Gene3 KINASE/DRUGGABLE GENOME/NA
2: Pathway2 Gene3/Gene1/Gene2 NA/KINASE/DRUGGABLE GENOME
3: Pathway3       Gene1/Gene4                  KINASE/NA
```